# Which is better: x < 5 or 5 > x?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 0;
alert(x < 5);
```

alerts "true" ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbgnh2e/)).

```
var x = 0;
alert(5 > x);
```

also alerts "true" ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzbgnh2e/1/)).

So which is better, `x < 5` or `5 > x`? They all return the same thing, but which is better in terms of performance, browser compatibility, etc? And why?

Comment: write your own tests to find out or try it on [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/)

Comment: I prefer `x < 5` for readability. The difference in performance isn't great enough to change my style. I don't know any browser that doesn't support both.

Comment: Even if there's a 5 nanosecond performance difference, you wouldn't be able to even detect it. Mute question IMO

Comment: I don't think it would matter, it's like asking which is better: `x + 1` or `1 + x`, the result is the same, both should be universally compatible and any differences in performance (if any) are probably so minor you wouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Browser compatibility?

Comment: Also because I don't think it really warrents a whole answer post: there's a browser difference? I think you'll have to go far far back to browsers that don't exist in the wild anymore to worry about browser compatibility for those symbols. don't get sucked down the performance optimization engine too much, you'll go insane.

Comment: You have 3K rep and are not a newbie. Why on earth would you even imagine that there was a browser compatibility issue here? Or a performance difference for that matter? If you suspected there was a performance issue, why not just run the performance tests yourself? Why would you bother to create a fiddle for this? We already know that `0 < 5`, and that JS engines know that. Why do you not mention the only conceivable possibility for choosing one over the other, which is readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second position is slightly more performant according to jsperf, but not in a meaningful way:

First postion results:

```
alert(x < 5);
```

715,232,209
±2.25%
fastest

Second Position results:

```
alert(5 > x);
```

722,609,214
±1.34%
fastest

Source: http://jsperf.com/equation-position

Comment: its certainly interesting that one is more performant, but barely noticable by any sane person though

Comment: I'm testing between `alert(x < 5);` and `alert(5 > x);`. Not `alert(x < 5);` and `alert(x > 5);` ...

Comment: Here's the test fixed: http://jsperf.com/stackoverflowgreaterorless/2 SAME perf on Chrome (0.21% perf benefit)

Comment: @agconti looks like 5 > x is faster than the first test you might want to edit that.

Comment: Your conclusion from the jsperf is wrong. The correct conclusion is "there is not statistically significant different in performance between the two". And why on earth would there be? And if there was so what? IMHO this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=1;
var pre = new Date().getTime();
for(var i=0;i<5000;i++){
    console.log(x<5)
}
var cur = new Date().getTime();
console.info(cur-pre);

var pre = new Date().getTime();
for(var i=0;i<5000;i++){
    console.log(5>x)
}
var cur = new Date().getTime();
console.info(cur-pre);
</script>
```

run in chrome 
the result:

```
5000  true
660
5000 true
604
```